# Current and Previous Month Revenue in Report

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

In Access 2013, I have a report showing revenue for each month of the year. I was success in getting a formula to name the previous month:

```
=Format$(DateAdd("m",-1,([ApptDate])),"mmmm",0,0)
```

What I am trying to get, is the revenue for the previous month for comparison, like a distribution chart. This is as close as I have gotten to something working, but the sum of the revenue for the previous month is too low (maybe only for a day's revenue?) Could anyone please help me put the following formula in the right order with right parameters to get the date needed?

```
=Sum(DateAdd("m",-1,([revenue])))
```

Comment: That expression really makes no sense. Review http://allenbrowne.com/subquery-01.html#AnotherRecord

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correctly, you could use the *DSum* function by setting as criteria the month of the date to the previous month.

```
=DSum("[revenue]","YourTableName","Month([ApptDate])=" & Month(DateAdd("m",-1,Date())))
```

Comment: This is what I entered, and it was accepted, but came up on the report `#Error`. Another suggestion?
`=DSum("[Revenue]","[Appointment]","Month([ApptDate])=" & Month(DateAdd("m",-1,Date())))`

Comment: Try `"Revenue" ` and `"Appointment"` without the `[]` brackets.

Comment: Each line now renders the same amount `8958.75`, which is not meaningful. Your initial iteration rendered the same result, but I had made type resulting in the error. It's a complex formula. Any more suggestions? I appreciate your help!

Comment: It's getting the same result because each and every line goes back one month from today's date. You need to change `Date()` to the date field for which you want to go back one month.

Comment: I've been trying to make this works in various ways. Kostas gave me this but it renders sums that are roughly twice the amount as the following month.  `=DSum("[revenue]","tblAppointment","Month([ApptDate])=" & Month(DateAdd("m",-1,[ApptDate])))` .... I'll keep trying, but if anyone has an extra suggestion, it'd be appreciated.